# Yii2 Pjax Delete not working

Tags: php, yii2, crud, pjax

I am trying to make an Ajax GridView using Pjax with delete button. Deleting goes with no Ajax. I am new to Yii2 so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**index.php**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'countries']) ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'title',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                    ]);
                },
            ]
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{   
    $model = new Category();
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Category::find(),
    ]);
    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

This is public function actionIndex() in the **Controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Category();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Category::find(),
    ]);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        $model = new Category();
    }
    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you specified Pjax::end(); In your above code it is missing after gridview.

Comment: My solution work like a charm....i personally used in my Project

Answer (score 3):

`data-method` and `data-confirm` don't let you create ajax request via pjax, you should implements your own confirmation dialog and drop POST verb filter, or you can implements your own ajax plugin with confirmation dialog and specifying http method.

Also, i think, there must be way to extend pjax plugin by confirmation dialog, but Yii2 don't provide this by default.

Answer (score 3):

first of all remove 'data-confirm' and 'data-method' => 'post'. pjax not going to work.
If you want to implement a confirm box with action button, here is what I would do in my view index.php file ..

```
<?php  Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-container']); 
echo GridView::widget([
    'test' => function ($url, $dataProvider) {
    return Html::a('Test',
        ['/site/test'],
        ['title'=>'Test',
         'onclick' => "if (confirm('ok?')) {
              $.ajax('/site/test', {
                  type: 'POST'
              }).done(function(data) {
                   $.pjax.reload({container: '#pjax-container'});
              });
          }
          return false;
          ",
          ]);
        },
    ])
Pjax::end();
?>
```

and in my controller

```
public function actionTest()
{

    if (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
}
```

This way you would have confirmation etc. as well. If you want you may use other third party bootstrap confirmation etc. and will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'model-grid']);
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    //...
    [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete}',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'action-column'],
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => 'Delete',
                        'data-pjax' => '#model-grid',
                    ]);
                },
            ],
        ],
    ],
]); 
Pjax::end(); ?>
```

In controller

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    $searchModel = new ModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try modify actionDelete()

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{   
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    return \yii\web\Response::redirect(['index'] , 302 , false);
    // return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

because Controller->redirect() can not disable ajaxCheck , you need use Response to do this.

I have create the same issue in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11058.

Comment: +1 also for the feature request on GitHub! This method works well also with data-confirm & data-method="post"

Answer (score 1):

Can use like this:

in view:

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
  $options = [
    'title' => Yii::t('common', 'delete'),
    'aria-label' => Yii::t('common', 'delete'),
    'data-pjax' => 'w0',//id
    'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
    'data-method' => 'post',
    'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger'
  ];
  return Html:: a('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i>', [
    'delete',
    'id' => $model -> id
  ], $options);
}
```

in controller:

```
$this -> findModel($id) -> delete ();
$searchModel = new AdminSearch();
//get the referer url
$url = Yii::$app -> request -> referrer;
$arr = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($arr, $output);//get the $_GET array
$dataProvider = $searchModel -> search($output);
return $this -> render('index', [
  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add `Pjax::end();` at end of the gridview
then specify:

```
    'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key)
    {
         return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                'data-method' => 'post',
      ]);
   },
```

Note that you don't need to specify  `'data-pjax' => '0'` because it disables the pjax link.

For more details check this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)

Your controller should be:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{   
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Comment: Updated. Please change your controller code and then check.

Comment: checked but still the same, I think because of that "return $this->redirect(['index']);" in the controller

Comment: I have the same problem, delete sends a normal request, not an AJAX request.

Comment: data-confirm currently disables the pjax request see this issue https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8582

Comment: so you can't delete in gridview using pjax if you use data-confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `data-method` and `data-confirm` because `Pjax` not supported that.

After removing both still not workign,yes because of below code of your controler does not allow Pjax get Request.

```
return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'], // **remove this**
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

You need to use Pjax Post Method
Apply this in Your Pjax

```
'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']
```